# Count Images on Amazon Product Detail Page Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im new to coding with Python. So please bear with me Im trying to find the number of product images a Product has on Amazon. 
1. I cant seem to get it work correctly? 
2. Is there a way to insert a list of ASINS so they can all print out with the number?
Thanks!

```html
import bs4
import webbrowser
import requests
File = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MRXQPJ5')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(File.text, 'html.parser' )
elems = soup.select('ul.a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-button-list a-vertical a-spacing-top-micro > li ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Amazon render it's page using javascript, the content is generated at client side, instead of server-side.

When you use requests you get the content at server-side. To get the content generated in client-side, you must use selenium or dryscrape, for example.

Here's a working code that will count the number of items for a list of product ids.

**Code:**

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import lxml.html as html
import lxml.html.clean as clean

urls = ['B017TSPK5K', 'B00B96KLCQ', 'B01MZ9E6CG']

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

for url in urls:
    amazon_url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/{}".format(url)

    browser.get(amazon_url)
    content = browser.page_source

    cleaner = clean.Cleaner()
    content = cleaner.clean_html(content)
    doc = html.fromstring(content)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

    soup_li = soup.find_all('li', {'class':'a-spacing-small item a-declarative'})

    print("Product ID: {} has {} images.".format(url, len(soup_li)))

browser.close()
```

**Output:**

```
'Product ID: B017TSPK5K has 2 images.'
'Product ID: B00B96KLCQ has 5 images.'
'Product ID: B01MZ9E6CG has 3 images.'
```

Comment: Thanks!  this looks like it works but I keep getting an error on Chrome "You are using unsupported comand line flag -ignore certificate errors"

Comment: Once you launch `Chrome` go to `about:flags` and then `Disable` this particular flag. Or you can setup a `Chrome Profile` before you start the `webdriver`...

Comment: I got it to work on FirefoxDriver but the                                                        ('li', {'class':'a-spacing-small item a-declarative'}) is showing 0 images